# How to set new value to existing query string Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, url, query-string, blazor

I'm attempting to change a query string paramater without reloading the page. I have a `DateTime` Date value that I'm attempting to turn into a string and put into the url. Say, for the sake of this question that it is:

```cs
DateTime? Date = new DateTime(2020, 9, 4);
```

So, my url could begin looking like:

```
https://localhost:44346/Events?d=2020-10-18
```

and after I do whatever magic must be done, it ends up like:

```
https://localhost:44346/Events?d=2020-10-04
```

I have attempted using `NavigationManager` and `QueryHelpers` like the following, but I've had no luck:

```
QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(navManager.Uri, "d", Date?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: Can you describe "had no luck" ?  I think navManager.Uri already has a querystring.

Comment: had no luck"" in that context means it doesn't work. ```navManager.Uri``` is equal to "https://localhost:44346/Events?d=2020-10-18" so it does already have a querystring. However, when I tried it using ```navManager.ToAbsoluteUri("Events").ToString()``` instead, it still doesn't work

Comment: And you do have a `[Parameter] d`, right?

Comment: No I do not, ```[Parameter] d``` would only work if it was in the form of ```https://localhost:44346/Events/2020-10-04```. I'm not having any issue getting the current query string, just setting it.

Comment: No, parameters work with ?d= as well. But do you want to create an `<a>` or use NavigateTo() ? That might matter. There was an issue about navigating to the same page, can't find it so quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out this demo

```cs
    @page "/counter"
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
    @using System.Web 
    @inject NavigationManager navManager
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeUrl">Change url</button>
    <br />
    demonstrate lack of page reload
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddItem">Add item</button>
    @foreach (var item in list)
    {
        @item
    }
    
    @code {
    
        private List<string> list = new List<string>()
        {
            "Test string"
        };
    
        private void AddItem()
        {
            var uri = navManager.ToAbsoluteUri(navManager.Uri);
    
            if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("d", out var param))
            {
                list.Add(param.First());
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add("d is empty");
            }
        }
    
        DateTime dateCounter = DateTime.Today;
        private void ChangeUrl()
        {
            dateCounter = dateCounter.AddDays(1);
    
            string url = RemoveQueryStringByKey(navManager.Uri, "d");
            var query = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "d", dateCounter.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") } };
    
            navManager.NavigateTo(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, query));
        }
    
        public static string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string url, string key)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(url);
    
            // this gets all the query string key value pairs as a collection
            var newQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
    
            // this removes the key if exists
            newQueryString.Remove(key);
    
            // this gets the page path from root without QueryString
            string pagePathWithoutQueryString = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
    
            return newQueryString.Count > 0
                ? String.Format("{0}?{1}", pagePathWithoutQueryString, newQueryString)
                : pagePathWithoutQueryString;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From .NET 6.0 onwards, there's a built-in method for this ([`NavigationManagerExtensions.GetUriWithQueryParameter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanagerextensions.geturiwithqueryparameter)):

```csharp
var newUrl = navManager.GetUriWithQueryParameter("d", Date?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```